# iptables moving rule in a list

Tags: android, linux, firewall, iptables

i have 2 rules of iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 6.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT
```

is there a function or a command that will swap the rules to be like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 6.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 40):

First check the line number:

```
iptables -nL --line-numbers
```

Delete based on line:

```
iptables -D INPUT {line}
```

Insert where you would like it to be:

```
iptables -I INPUT {line} -i lo -p tcp --dport {port} -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "This rule is here for this reason"
```

Found at these sources:

[Delete Rule](http://major.io/2007/02/09/delete-single-iptables-rules/)

[Insert Rule](https://snipt.net/johan_adriaans/insert-an-iptables-rule-on-a-specific-line-number-with-a-comment-and-restore-all-rules-after-reboot/)

Comment: Thank you. -I seem to be better than -A which is shown in most examples.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to mention that `-I {line}` and `-A {line}` add rule to specified line moving everything else down. For example, `-I INPUT 3` will move the previous `rule #3` to `rule #4`.

Answer (score 8):

We had an issue with the order of some rules, and the most efficient way I found to change this was with two tools:

1. iptables-save
2. iptables-restore

First dump the rules into a file:

```
sudo iptables-save > /root/iptrules.txt
```

Then edit the file with your favorite text editor:

```
sudo vim /root/iptrules.txt
```

Make the necessary movements and then restore the rules:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /root/iptrules.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such command to swap two iptables rules.

You can just delete and insert them into appropriate position.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program named `iptables-persistent` which make iptable's rules persistent as a os service. this service include a configuration file as the `iptables-save` export.

So you can reorder the lines in the configuration file and restart the service.

```
sudo service iptables-persistent restart
```

So easy!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of -A use -D to delete and then add again

iptables -D INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP

iptables -D INPUT -s 6.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT

Now add with swaped value

iptables -A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 6.5.5.5 -j DROP

Answer (score 0):

Let's assuem your INPUT chain has only these two rules, so their ID number would be `1` and `2` respectively for `-A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP` and `-A INPUT -s 6.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT`

Now, let's switch them:

`iptables -R INPUT 2 -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP
iptables -R INPUT 1 -s 6.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -R` is a command to Replace a rule already existed in iptables with another.

Its usage is: `iptables -R [chain name] [line number] [new rule]`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

If those rules are permanent and therefore located in the `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `etc/iptables/rules/v6` files, then you can just edit both files and move the rules to fit the desired order, something like:

```
-A INPUT -s 6.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP
```

Restart iptables (`service iptables restart`)

---

**Solution 2**

What I would do if there were only a few rules, like in your case, will be to delete the first rule and recreate it:

```
iptables -nL --line-numbers
```

Get the number of the rule you want to reorder (in your example would be 1) delete it and create it again, this will place the newlly created rule last in the table:

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -j DROP`
```